# Removing all comments from JavaServerPages

Tags: jsp, comments

I am interested in programmatically stripping out all comments from JSPs.

Ideally, I would have access to a CLI tool that accepts a JSP file as an input and it would output the source code with all comments stripped out. It should be able to remove all Java and HTML comments.

I need this to normalize code for three way comparison of source code that has been customized from out of the box vendor code as a part of a system upgrade.

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Comment: This goes back several years but I ended up having a Tata consultant write some programs to do the cleanup. I was thinking that this could be done with a tool like Meld which has comment ignoring features and therefore already has the algorithms build into the code. However, I am not sure if there is any exposed API.